# Do device administrators have access to other user accounts?

Tags: multi-user, device-administrator

I have installed an Enterprise App Store application, provided by my employer. The app says that I need to make it a device administrator in order to use it, but I do not want to give it admin access to my phone.

My question is, if I create another user (work, for example) on my phone, install the app as the work user, and then make it a device administrator, will it be able to access the apps and data on my original user account?

My Phone: Nexus 6P (Android 6.0.1) stock

Comment: Which Android version? Are you talking of creating a guest user for *work*in your example ? What  exactly do you mean by admin access?

Comment: @beeshyams No, I am not creating a guest user. I'm creating a new and permanent user on my device called "work." By admin access, I mean that I do not want to let the app be a device administrator (without which it won't run).

Comment: I have the same phone and do the same thing. Work account require the "Google Apps device policy" app to be a device admin. It is admin on my work account, but does not show up in the device administrators list on my main, personal account. Not sure if it really has no access, though.

Comment: The wipeData() method of the Device Administrator API states "Wiping the primary user will cause the device to reboot", hinting that the API is per-user, so your personal account may be unaffected (to be confirmed) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData(int). Note that there is no API to list installed applications on the device in the Device Administrator API, you can only check security settings, lock and wipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the same phone and do the same thing. Work account require the >"Google Apps device policy" app to be a device admin. It is admin on my >work account, but does not show up in the device administrators list on my >main, personal account. Not sure if it really has no access, though.

Thanks @personne3000 for your suggestion. I did the same and it does not show up as an administrator on my main account.